# Need to dynamically add menuItem to HighCharts contextButton w/function defined by variable

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to dynamically add a menu item to my HighChart to support dynamic drilldowns with a function name that is dynamically generated. I'm able to successfully add new menuItems to the existing contextButton when using statically defined functions like alerts, however, when I have a function defined using a var it won't invoke the proper function.
the following is working:

```
var chartOptions = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: myChartDiv,
            zoomType: 'x',
            type: 'area'
            }, 
        exporting: {
            enabled: true,
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    menuItems: [{
                        text: 'My Test',
                        onclick: function() {
                            alert('success!');
                        }
                    }]
                }}
            }};
```

However, as soon as I want to add a new menu item with a function defined in a variable, the call defined by the variable is skipped. ie:

```
var c1 = "chart1";
var c2 = "chart2";
var drilldownMethod = "toggleCharts('" + c1 + "','" + c2 + "')";
var newDrilldown = {
    text: Show Chart 2,
    onclick: function () {alert('test1'); drilldownMethod; alert('test2') }
};
chartOptions.exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push(newDrilldown);
```

I do see the new menu item "Show Chart 2", and when I click it, I do get the alerts 'test1' and 'test2' appear; however, the function in the string variable "drilldownMethod" is never invoked (there's an alert in that method as well to prove the point).

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

`drilldownMethod` is a string, not a function call, that's why you don't see it executing. This should work:

```
chartOptions.exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
    text: 'Show Chart 2',
    onclick: function () {
        toggleCharts("chart1", "chart2");
    }
});
```